# Type error in line 630 of JQuery

Tags: jquery

when I run my codes

I am getting an error in console as

```
TypeError: object is undefined
length = object.length,
```

it points to line 630 of jQuery.js  each: function( object, callback, args )

But how can I identify the exact reason for the same error?

Comment: which version of jquery?

Comment: You might want to share some code on this one.

Comment: There **may** be a little red triangle to the left of the error message - click it and you will see a stack trace and can tell what part of your script the error originated at. Alternatively, if you don't have a large code base, just look for your `$.each` calls - one of them is trying to iterate over a non-array/non-object.

Comment: If your jQuery library has 630 lines, it must be the uncompressed, development version. Better use the compressed, production version.

Answer (score 0):

The function begins with

```
each: function( object, callback, args ) {
    var name, i = 0,
        length = object.length
```

If you pass an undefined `object`, `object.length` will throw an error.

Then, it isn't jQuery's problem, it's yours, because you use

```
jQuery.each(variableYouThinkItsAnObjectButIsUndefined, func);
```

You can fix it using

```
if(variableYouThinkItsAnObjectButIsUndefined)
    jQuery.each(variableYouThinkItsAnObjectButIsUndefined, func);
```